# How to handle onchange event in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a select box. On select select box value my page will reload. How can I handle this situation in `sails.js` .
I am new in `sails.js`. Please give some solutions if anyone can do.

```
<select name="gender" id="gender" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
   <option value="">Select Gender</option>
   <option value="M" <%= (gender == 'M')? 'selected':'' %>>Male</option>
   <option value="F" <%= (gender == 'F')? 'selected':'' %>>Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the page to reload when the value changes? What is `this.handleChange`?

Comment: I want to reload page when value changes.

Comment: You are not understing how EJS works! It is not reactive like Angular or some front-end framework, but a way to render HTML server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use some frontend framework, or, if you want to use the embedded ejs, then in your assets/js folder add jquery and in your view add a script tag in which you can add an onChange event handler to your select.